# calling method via reflection that takes an Action<T>. All of the method, the containing class and T are marked internal

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an internal method like this

```
void Foo(Action<DB> act)
```

the class DB is in the same assembly and also marked internal. I can work out how to get a methodinfo for Foo but I cannot work out how to set up the callback `act` in the calling code. This is what I have so far (as an added spice I want to call another internal method from inside the callback)

```
    var tt = eng.GetType().Assembly;
    var dd = tt.GetType("Internal.DB");
    var kk = typeof(Action<>);
    Type[] targs =  { dd };
    var qq = kk.MakeGenericType(targs);
    MethodInfo dynMethod = eng.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { qq },null);
    dynMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] {
        ((Action<object>)(db=>{
       MethodInfo dynMethod2 = db.GetType().GetMethod("Wiz", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        dynMethod2.Invoke(db);
    })) });
```

my problem is here (I think)

```
((Action<object>)(db=>{
```

I really need

```
((Action<DB>)(db=>{
```

but I cannot do that (DB is internal), the one with `object` compiles but fails at run time saying that the object is of the wrong type.

Comment: Could you expand your example to be compileable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed very little of your example and got code which compiles and runs to completion. Is there a chance your DB.Wiz() is throwing an exception? If not we may need more info about which runtime is giving you this issue or a more complete example. Below example properly outputs `"Hello, World!"`

**.Net 4.6.1 Solution**

ConsoleApp project, has reference to Class Library namespace `Internal`. I've changed your `dynMethod2.Invoke()` to pass an empty object[] as your example did not compile with one parameter to `Invoke`. Also removed redundant parens around your lambda expression.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Internal.Eng eng = new Internal.Eng();

    var tt = eng.GetType().Assembly;
    var dd = tt.GetType("Internal.DB");
    var kk = typeof(Action<>);
    Type[] targs = { dd };

    var qq = kk.MakeGenericType(targs);

    MethodInfo dynMethod = eng.GetType().GetMethod("Foo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { qq }, null);

    dynMethod.Invoke(eng, new object[] {
        (Action<object>)(db=>{
            MethodInfo dynMethod2 = db.GetType().GetMethod("Wiz", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            dynMethod2.Invoke(db, new object[]{ });
        })
    });
}
```

---

**Class library `Internal` namespace.**

```
using System;

namespace Internal
{
    public class Eng
    {
        internal void Foo(Action<DB> act) => act(new DB());
    }

    internal class DB
    {
        internal void Wiz()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I do this the dynMethod.Invoke throws 'System,.Reflection.TargetException, Object does not match target type'.I assumed this was because `Action<object>` != `Action<DB>`

Comment: @pm100 What runtime are you on

Comment: dang - I am so dumb, I was passing the wrong ins6ance type to the invoke - you correcte4d it and I didnt see. TY

Answer (score 0):

A bit hard figuring out exactly what it is you're trying to do, but if Wiz is a method of DB that accepts no parameters then I believe you're after something like this:

```
dynMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] {
    ((Action<DB>)(db=> {
        MethodInfo dynMethod2 = db.GetType().GetMethod("Wiz", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        dynMethod2.Invoke(db, null);
})) });
```